# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/InputDStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I started learning spark-streaming-kafka but I can't run the program properly. An error constantly pops up:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/InputDStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "KafkaSpark"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.13"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.1.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "3.1.1"
```

My program:

```
package com.work
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._


object KafkaSpark extends App {
  val conf =
    new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaSpark").setMaster("local[1]")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> "localhost:9092",
    ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> "groupId",
    ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[
      StringDeserializer
    ]
  )
  val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )
  stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
}
```

Did I enter the app name incorrectly?
Maybe did I install spark wrong?
And separately kafka and spark work normally

Comment: You could try to remove the `provided` from your sbt file

Comment: it makes very little sense to use Spark Streaming in 2021st.  Use Spark Structured Streaming instead

Comment: @werner,it worked. thanks

Comment: @AlexOtt, is spark streaming outdated?

Comment: The DStream based - yes. Structured Streaming is the way forward.

Comment: Look to this free book: https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly